# Jackson Json UTF16

Tags: jackson

I'm new to Java and in C# this stuff is pretty straightforward but I'm struggling with it in Java.

I'm entering some Chinese characters in a text box on the form but when Jackson Json serialises the object, it converts the Chinese chars into random bits of text. Does any one have any idea what I need to do with Jackson Json to preserve the characters so that I can pass them to the C# Web API service?

The code I'm using is below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(userAddress);
```

When the mapper de-serialises the userAddress object which contains the Chinese chars, it converts them to random chars within the json string before invoking the C# Web API. How do I preserve them or do I need to do encode them as bytes and then decode them in the C# Web API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has to do more with Encoding than Jackson. One of the advantages of using UTF-8 is because it supports Chinese Characters. I tested exactly what you reported and Jackson converted the characters just fine. Now you should check what encoding is you JVM running on, if it's running on a encoding that doesn't support Chinese you might have that problem

Comment: Thank you for responding. It was an older version of Jackson JSON which was causing the issue. Upgrading it from 1.8.2 to 2.5 resolved that issue.